# Why is my Merge function giving weird answers?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

I just made a simple merge function using a numpy array. The code is below, and it should be fairly
simple, am I not implementing the array correctly?

```
import numpy as np

def Merge(leftlist, rightlist):
    len1 = len(leftlist)
    len2 = len(rightlist)
    lfirst = 0
    rfirst = 0
    merge  = 0
    newlist = np.empty(len1 + len2, dtype = int)
    while lfirst < len1 and rfirst < len2:
        if leftlist[lfirst] < rightlist[rfirst]:
            newlist[merge] = leftlist[lfirst]
            lfirst += 1
            merge += 1

        else:
            newlist[merge] = rightlist[rfirst]
            rfirst += 1
            merge += 1 
    
    return newlist
```

When I use Merge([5,6,9],[1,2,3]), it returns:

array([         1,          2,          3,  173670400, 1667330163,
1701601125]),

rather than array([1,2,3,5,6,9]). Not sure what is wrong about it.

Edit: I should mention that the leftlist and rightlist parameters are also numpy arrays in this case.

Comment: Why not just `sorted(leftlist+rightlist)` if they are lists or `np.sort(np.concatenate((leftlist, rightlist)))` if they are numpy arrays?

Comment: its because of `while lfirst < len1 and rfirst < len2` , revise that

Comment: you should proceed in two steps: merge and then sort, or the complexity will turn unfun quick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `Merge([5,6,9],[1,2,3])`, the `lfirst` stays 0, so `leftlist` is never read beyond the first element (the while loop never accounts for what to do with the list with greater value). The random elements you see is because you created an empty array first. If you run `Merge([5,6,9],[1,2,3])` again and again, the last 3 elements will change each time.

I edited your function to find your desired outcome (N.B. This sorts only if each passed list is already sorted):

```
def Merge(left, right):
    leftlist, rightlist = [list(left), list(right)]
    comparisons = 0
    newlist = []
    
    while leftlist or rightlist:
        try:
            x = leftlist.pop(0) if leftlist[0] < rightlist[0] else rightlist.pop(0)
        except:
            x = leftlist.pop(0) if leftlist else rightlist.pop(0)
        newlist.append(x)
        comparisons += 1
                
    return np.array(newlist), comparisons
```

Output:

```
Merge([5,6,9],[1,2,3]) # (array([1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9]), 6)
```

So here, there were 6 comparisons.